# why is there the error "No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project" when I write mvn help:effective-pom in the command prompt?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm reading a tutorial about maven and it should be mentioned that I know nothing about it. I have done first and second chapter successfully which was about it's setup. but in chapter 3 which is "Maven Pom" I have a problem. In last paragraph it says to make a "pom.xml" file in any directory you wish and write this in it:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>com.companyname.project-group</groupId>
   <artifactId>project</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>

</project>
```

and then it says  that an easy way to look at the default configurations of the super POM is by running the following command: `mvn help:effective-pom` in the command prompt.

But when I try this, I get this error:

```
No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project
```

This is the tutorial I mentioned above: [maven tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_quick_guide.htm)

Why there is no plugin help in my repository folder?! and how I can get it?

This is the output of mvn --version in the cmd:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version: 1.6.0_13
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows Vista",version:"6.8"
```

This is the rezult of mvn -X help:effective-pom(first ten lines)

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-3.1.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
```

Comment: Does your file actually say `<artifactId&gtproject</artifactId>`?  If so, change `&gt` to `>`.

Comment: I corrected that but the Error changed to "No plugin found for prefix 'help' in the current project" @ajb

Comment: Can you check what `mvn --version` says?

Comment: Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.3
Java version:1.6.0_13
OS name: "windows vista"

Comment: seems like effective-pom has been deprecated as per "http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/examples/describe-configuration.html" ,,,, you must have been using on cutting edge maven build, it would be interesting to know the output of <code>mvn --version<code>

Comment: The output of mvn --version is: Apach-maven-3.2.3
java version:1.6.0_13
OS name:"window vista"

Comment: @shakiba Please make full screenshot of the output....@Xinus: effective-pom is **not** deprecated.

Comment: I can't add an image because of my reputation, but the exact out put is 
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.3
Apache Maven 3.2.3(33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4;)
Java version: 1.6.0_13, vendor: sun Mirosystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "Windows Vista", version: "6.0", family: "window"
@khmarbaise

Comment: Try to delete your local repository ${HOME}/.m2/repository and retry `mvn help:effective-pom`...

Comment: I retried but there was no change in the rezult, It seems that it fails to download! @khmarbaise

Comment: Ok..than we are the root cause of the problem. Download problems..which you have to solve first..Are you beding a proxy ?

Comment: No I don't use a proxy, I didn't get what should I download?!@khmarbaise

Comment: @Shakiba: mvn needs you to be connected to the internet while you run any mvn command, Please check if any of earlier console traces suggest any connection failures while running this command. you can always do 'mvn help:effective-pom >> log.txt', After running this you can check log.txt to see any problems

Comment: Had the same issue. It seems my console did not have enough right to modify necessary directory. Re-ran from admin mode and working fine.

Answer (score 10):

**Background Information**

When you execute `mvn help:effecitve-pom`, `help` is a prefix which represents a specific plugin while `effective-pom` is the goal from that plugin that should be executed.

The first thing Maven does is try to lookup the full plugin based on the given prefix (so in your case the prefix `help`). Normally it does this by checking the `/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml` file in your local repository (by default your local repository is stored under `%HOME%/.m2/repository`).

If this file doesn't exist then it tries to check it remotely (again default configuration would use maven central), and will then cache this file in your local repository with the following name: `maven-metadata-<remote-repo-id>.xml` (so for maven central it would be: `maven-metadata-central.xml`). If at this point it is unable to access this file remotely then it wont be able to find the plugin and will fail the build. This is exactly what you are experiencing.

**Your Issue**

There are two main reasons why it wont be able to resolve the plugin:

- the local files in your repository are corrupt in some way
- maven is unable to access the remote repository (so basically a problem with your internet connection).

You can use the debug flag `-X` when executing your maven build to receive more information about what is going on. For you executing the following:

```
mvn -X help:effective-pom
```

should provide information about how it is trying to resolve the plugin prefix. For example if I execute this command I see the following:

```
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix help from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/user/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
```

My locally cached file from the remote repository is up to date so it will just use that.

Do either `/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml` or `/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata-central.xml` exist in your local repository? If they don't then most likely you have an internet connection problem. If they do exist then they might be corrupt. What is the result of running with the `-X` flag, what information does it provide?

After all this usually the simplest solution is to delete your local repository (by default `%HOME%/.m2/repository`, but running maven with the `-X` flag will tell you exactly where it is), and execute maven again. By deleting the local repository you force maven to download everything again.

Comment: it is the rezult of mvn -X help:effective-pom(first 5 lines) @DB5 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Comment: what happens when you delete your local repository and run the command again? Actually where does maven think your local repository is located?

Comment: when i delete local repository and run the command again the same rezult happens. how can I understand "where does maven think local repository is located"?? I just know local repository is located in .m2

Comment: @shakiba: You probably are behind a firewall or proxy of some kind. You need to configure Maven to talk to it. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: but I don't use any proxy and I tried it even when my firewall turned off but the same thing happened. @AaronDigulla

Answer (score 0):

The command should work. If it doesn't, then that means you made a mistake in the setup of Maven or it printed more errors before that, namely that it could download plugins from Maven Central.

Delete the folder `%HOME%/.m2/repository/` and try again. Now look closely for any problems in the output of Maven.

If it still doesn't work, show us the content of `%HOME%/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/`

Comment: there is no "maven-help-plugin" ! but the set up has no problem because when I try mvn --version, the output is correctly the version of my maven. I don't know why it hasn't installed the help plugin? @Aaron Digulla

Comment: In fact, I don't know what should I have do to have the help plugin in the repository? @Aaron Digulla

Comment: The error message means that Maven can't download the plugins. That means there is something wrong with your Internet connection (which doesn't seem to be the case since you could download Maven itself) or there is something wrong with `https`. Try to upgrade your version of Java. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Like in a similar topic in stackoverflow, just use a plugin directly in the pom, for example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <testSource>1.8</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:deprecation</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a mirror of central you might need to define the prefix in  the plugin metadata file for your mirror.

The file

.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata-<mirror id>.xml

must contain

```
<plugin>
   <name>Maven Help Plugin</name>
   <prefix>help</prefix>
   <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Comment: While the above is true; if you change the file manually it will simply get overriden with the file coming from the mirror. You have to fix it at the mirror. In may case the mirror is an Artifactory virtual repo. That virtual repo included an actual repo where the metadata did not have the 'help' prefix. By deleting the metadata file from that repo it all worked as expected.