# No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project

Tags: maven, jdbc, installation

I want to add jdbc oracle to maven repository since it is not in repository, I have to run this command:

```
mvn install:install-file
-Dfile=D:\Temp\ojdbc6.jar 
-DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc6 -
 Dversion=11.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and run into this error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'install' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local ({my repository path}), central (https://repo.maven.
apache.org/maven2)]
```

any help would be appropriated.

Comment: This answer should give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26378059/1570834. Simply replace `help` with `install` and the answer is then valid.

Comment: @DB5 I read the answers, and check every thing. Every thing seems to be correct, I dont know what is mistake.

Comment: What do you see when you use the debug flag? (i.e. `mvn -X install:install-file...`). Have you tried deleting your local repository and trying again?

Comment: @DB5 this i sthe result of running with -X    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local 
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local .m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml

Comment: @DB5 yes, I delete the repository and again the same result.

Answer (score 3):

I recently got the same error and I tried this command. It worked.

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, there is a two-step process to resolve this issue:

1. **Configure Maven Proxy Configuration**

   1. Open Maven configuration file:

      - For Linux: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`
      - For Windows: `C:\users\username\.m2\settings.xml`
      - If you could find the file open it and search for `<proxies></proxies>` the segment.
      - If you cannot find the file, create a new file called `settings.xml` and add following xml tags `<settings></settings>`
      - Add the proxy configurations as below:

        ```
        <proxies>
            <proxy>
                <id>example-proxy</id>
                <active>true</active>
                <protocol>http</protocol>
                <host>proxy.example.com</host>
                <port>8080</port>
                <username>proxyuser</username>
                <password>somepassword</password>   
             <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
           </proxy>
        </proxies>
        ```
2. **Update Maven Libraries with a Working Extension**

   - Wagon HTTP lightweight library allows us to connect through NTLM proxies. This can be added as an extension to default Maven libraries.
   - Download the `wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar` from
     https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.2/wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar
   - Copy the downloaded file to `%M2_HOME%/lib/ext` folder.

Now you are ready to use Maven with your programs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your Maven configuration file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It should install Oracle JDBC to your repository and should install the necessary JARS.

https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39256/add-dependencies-to-maven-pom-xml-file/

Add it within the `dependencies` tag.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix ‘install’ in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/amitkumar/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

There are 2 steps we need to follow to fix this issues :
Step 1 : Open Maven configuration file: For Linux: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
If you could find the file open it and search for  the segment.
If you cannot find the file, create a new file called settings.xml and add following xml tags 
Add the proxy configurations as below:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/settings/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <proxies>
      <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>www-proxy.us.oracle.com</host>
            <port>80</port>
            <nonProxyHosts>adc2170275|*.oracle.com|*.oracleads.com|*.us.oracle.com|
                *.uk.oracle.com|*.ca.oracle.com|*.oraclecorp.com|
                *.oracleportal.com
              </nonProxyHosts>
      </proxy>
   </proxies>
</settings>
```

Step 2:
Update Maven Libraries with a Working Extension
Wagon HTTP lightweight library allows us to connect through NTLM proxies. This can be added as an extension to default Maven libraries.
Download the wagon-http-lightweight-2.2.jar from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-lightweight/2.2/wagon-http-lightweight-
2.2.jar
Copy the downloaded file to %M2_HOME%/lib/ext folder.